# Git commit from command line with SourceTree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

What I want is something like this: `stree /path/to/repo --commit hashcommit`?
Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is currently not possible.

When you run the `stree` command with the `--help` option, you will see the available commands and options:

```
stree --help
Usage: stree [--help] [path]
```

The only real parameter is the `path` one, which allows you to specify the repository to open, so `/path/to/repo` in your case. There's no option to jump to a specific commit at this time.

You can request a new feature through the `Help > Request a New Feature` menu entry.

Comment: thanks for the answer! do you know any gui tools which can provide such functionality?

Comment: Sorry, no, don't know about any tool like that.